# Dataset of international marriages

Tags: data-request, census

I'm looking for a dataset containing the following:

- for each country, number of weddings according to the spouses' nationalities
- if possible, yearly data and % of divorces.

For example, here is such [dataset about Koreans](http://www.index.go.kr/potal/main/EachDtlPageDetail.do?idx_cd=2430):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The United Nations Statistics Divisions publishes tables on marriages per country. While they do not break it down by nationality, they do provide a variety of demographic data.

http://unstats.un.org/unsd/Demographic/sconcerns/mar/mar2.htm

The BLS also publishes tables on marriage that contain some ethnicity information for the US:

http://www.bls.gov/opub/mlr/2013/article/marriage-and-divorce-patterns-by-gender-race-and-educational-attainment.htm

Answer (score 1):

Eurostat has data for [marriages](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-datasets/-/demo_marcz) and [divorces](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-datasets/-/demo_divcz) by broad group of **citizenship**.

In addition, [marriages](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-datasets/-/demo_marcb) and [divorces](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-datasets/-/demo_divcb) are also available by **country of birth**.